# pthread lock / unlock solution

Tags: linux, pthreads, vxworks

I want to reimplement the vxWorks functions taskLock() and taskUnlock().

Here is the original description of the vxWorks function.

```
* taskUnlock - enable task rescheduling
*
* This routine decrements the preemption lock count.  Typically this call is
* paired with taskLock() and concludes a critical section of code.
* Preemption will not be unlocked until taskUnlock() has been called as many
* times as taskLock().  When the lock count is decremented to zero, any tasks
* that were eligible to preempt the current task will execute.
*
* The taskUnlock() routine is not callable from interrupt service routines.
```

I use pthreads to reimplement the vxWorks tasks. So is there a possibility to do that?

If I understand right. If a function call taskLock, there will be no interruption of the following code until taskunlock is called.

I didn't find a solution in the web.

Comment: Why do you do it? What's your end goal?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin `I want to reimplement the vxWorks functions taskLock() and taskUnlock(). ` cause a have a vxwork dependent driver(but that is not context of this post)

Answer (score 2):

From the [v2lin Project on sourceforge.net/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/v2lin/files/v2lin/0.1/v2lin-0.1.tgz/download?use_mirror=heanet&download=) taskLock comments:

```
 taskLock - 'locks the scheduler' to prevent preemption of the current task
           by other task-level code.  Because we cannot actually lock the
           scheduler in a pthreads environment, we temporarily set the
           dynamic priority of the calling thread above that of any other
           thread, thus guaranteeing that no other tasks preempt it.
```

**Because we cannot actually lock the scheduler in a pthreads environment**